# How to bulk create and update Azure Key Vault secrets using scripts?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I have a scenerio where I need to fetch the secret list from '**A**' azure key vault and then create them in '**B**' azure keyvault. But the values will have to changes/updated while creating secrets in '**B**' azure keyvault. As I have many secrets so I am trying to perform it via a script.

I have tried to pull only secrets name from '**A**' azure keyvault and store into a CSV file using the below **AZ CLI** command:

```
az keyvault secret list --vault-name <<vault-name>> -o table > src.csv
```

Now I want to use the same CSV file where I can update the new values for the secrets fetched and use it to create/update the secrets in the '**B**' azure keyvault using any **Powershell/AZ CLI/Bash script**.

Has anyone faced this similar kind of scenerio? Is it do able? If yes, then please guide me.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: Yes this resolved the issue. Thanks @CharlesXu

Comment: Gald to hear that. If you don't mind please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you're able to do it. I assume you would use the bash script to achieve it, then here is the example script:

```
az keyvault secret list --vault-name keyvault_A --query [].name -o tsv > /mnt/d/ubuntu/temp.csv
input="/mnt/d/ubuntu/temp.csv"
while IFS= read -r secret
do
    # echo $secret
    echo "Create secret name : $secret"
    az keyvault secret set --vault-name keyvault_B --name $secret --value $secret
done < $input
az keyvault secret list --vault-name keyvault_B -o table
```

As I see you would update/change the value of the secrets, so I only get the name of the secrets and the list also cannot get the value for you. If you need to update/change the value of the secrets according to the existing value, you can get the value in the `while` loop via the command `az keyvault secret show`.

Answer (score 3):

Here you have two steps how to read secret names from one Key Vault and write to another one. You only need to add logic to update new values through file.

Read secret names:

```
$secrets = az keyvault secret list --vault-name kv-stack | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object @{Label='Name'; Expression={$_.Id.split("/")[-1]}}
```

Write to another key vault:

```
 $secrets | ForEach-Object {az keyvault secret set --vault-name kv-stack-2 --name $_.Name --value something}
```